# Why is this logical formula invalid for expressing the statement "anything bought it not human"?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

In my first order logic notes, one example that comes up is to express that "anything bought is not human". Is says this can be expressed as:

$\forall x(\exists y \, bought(y,x) \rightarrow \neg human(x))$

where $bought(y,x)$ means y bought x. It explicitly says not to express it as:

$\forall x \exists y( \, bought(y,x) \rightarrow \neg human(x))$

I read the second one as for all x, there exists y, such that if y bought x, then x is not human. I read the first one as for all x, if there exists a y such that y bought x, then x is not human.

So how does the second formula not express the fact that anything bought is not human? They both seem equivalent in this regard.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [math.se].

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Okay, how do i migrate it?

Comment: I flagged the moderators.

Comment: The first statement is historically, and probably currently, false.

Answer (score 3):

The formulas are not equivalent since for example the first one is unfortunately not true in the real world – there are human beings that were bought – but the second one is true in the real world. I have never bought a human being, so I am the witnessing $y$ for any $x$ – for every $x$, if I bought it, then it is not human. By the way this shows that even the stronger statement $∃y ∀x (bought(y, x) → ¬human(x))$ is true in the real world.

If you don't like the real world model, you can build a toy formal model. For example our model may consist of two entities $A$, $B$ such that $A$ is a human that bought itself and $B$ bought nothing. $A$ witnesses that the first statement is false. $B$ witnesses that the second statement is true.

You may also analyze the statements syntactically:
the second formula is equivalent to $∀x∃y(¬bought(y, x) ∨ ¬human(x))$, which is equivalent to $∀x((∃y¬bought(y, x)) ∨ (∃y¬human(x)))$, which is equivalent to $∀x((∃y¬bought(y, x)) ∨ ¬human(x))$. On the other hand, the first formula is equivalent to $∀x(¬(∃y(bought(y, x))) ∨ ¬human(x))$. So the key difference is the contravariance of the first argument of the implication.

Comment: I'm not basing anything on the real world, just expressing the statement "anything bought is not human" with the predicate symbols bought and human

Comment: @Logan545: If two formulas are equivalent, then they are equivalent in every model, including the real world (given that the real world may be interpreted as a model of the given language, which is true in our case).

Comment: @Logan545 Since basing questions on false premises is asking for trouble, you should avoid it. Or I could say that you claim that slaves are not human. Which actually _is_ what you are claiming.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't care about the real world meaning, but the underpinning logic, we'll simply use the relation $B$ and univariate $C$ to shorten the math statements.

The first statement is of the form: $\forall x~((\exists y~B(x,y))\to\neg C(x))$.   Anything will not satisfy $C$ if it is $B$-related to something.

The second statement is of the form: $\forall x~\exists y~(B(x,y))\to\neg C(x))$.    Everything has something such that, the former does not satisfy $C$ if it is $B$-related to the second.

---

In the universe $\{a,b,c\}$ where $B(a,c), C(a), C(c)$ are the only facts for $B,C$, then $\forall x~\exists y~(B(x,y)\to\neg C(x))$ is true but $\forall x~((\exists y~B(x,y))\to\neg C(x))$ is false.

---

Using equivalences:

$${\quad\forall x~((\exists y~B(x,y))\to C(x))\\ \equiv \forall x~((\neg \exists y~B(x,y))\vee C(x))\qquad\text{implication equivalence}\\\equiv \forall x~((\forall y~\neg B(x,y))\vee C(x))\qquad\text{quantifier duality}\\\equiv \forall x~\forall y~(\neg B(x,y)\vee C(x))\qquad~~~\text{quantifier distribution}\\\equiv \forall x~\forall y~(B(x,y)\to C(x))\qquad\quad\text{implication equivalence}}$$

Which is certainly not equivalent with $\forall x~\exists y~(B(x,y)\to C(x))$, the form of the second statement.